# An Injective Composition of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that A is a linear transformation from vector spaces U to V and that B is a linear transformation from vector spaces V to W. Suppose further that B composed of A is an injective composition of the aforementioned linear transformations.

For this composition to be injective, do A and B have to be injective? My intuition tells me that B HAS to be injective while it is not required for A to be injective. Also, how would one prove that either A or B have to be injective.

Also, I am quite fairly new to this site and I have no idea how I can use all of the math symbols and notation that everyone else here is using, so if someone can help me out on that then that would be great.

Comment: It's just the opposite. Math symbols: Put the formula into dollar symbols: $ax=b$. Here I put ax=b between dollar symbols.

Comment: `$A$` produces $A$. And `\`$A$\`` produces `$A$`.

Comment: The [Mathjax FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is what you're looking for, with respect to typesetting.

Comment: `$A$`Thanks, Roland. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is not injective, there are two elements, $x,y \in U$ such that $x \neq y$, but $A(x) = A(y)$.  Then $B$ is stuck, it can't tell $A(x)$ and $A(y)$ apart and sends them both to the same place, so $B(A(x)) = B(A(y))$ and the composition is not injective.

Depending on the details of your notation, it's possible for the image of $A$ to not be all of $V$, so that $B$ could fail to be injective, but $A$ can't send two elements to places that $B$ conflates.  I doubt that you are using notation this way; I expect that the image of $A$ is all of $V$ and the image of $B$ is all of $W$.  In this case, for the composition to be injective, both $A$ and $B$ must be so:

- Were $B$ not injective, there would be two elements of the image of $A$ that were sent to the same element of $W$.  Since these came from (at least) two elements $U$, the composition is not injective.
- Were $A$ not injective, the argument above would apply and the composition would not be injective.

Therefore, if the composition is injective, so are $A$ and $B$.

Comment: "I expect that the image of $A$ is all of $V$" Why do you do this? The dimension of $V$ could be larger than that of $U$. Then this is definitely not the case. And then, $B$ is not necessarily injective in order that $BA$ be injective.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : Because rather a lot of introductory texts define a map "$a:B \rightarrow C$" so that $C$ is the image of $B$ through $a$ so they do not have to discriminate between image and codomain.  Since, also, the image of $B$ is necessarily in the category of vector spaces, nothing is lost by doing so.

Comment: "a lot of introductory texts define a map "$a:B\to C$" so that $C$ is the image of $B$": I strongly disagree. In particular, it is pretty standard to define linear maps $T : V\to W$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, no matter what the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are or whether $W$ is the image of $T$ or not. And I think, the point of the exercise is to see that $A$ need not be surjective so that $B$ - after $A$ - acts only on $im(A)$ so that $BA$ may well be injective while $B$ is not.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : Since you like quotations so much, which part of " it's possible for the image of A to not be all of V, so that B could fail to be injective, but A can't send two elements to places that B conflates" fails to address the concern you are expressing?

Comment: I read this and I was fine with it. But right thereafter you write that you expect anyways that $AU = V$, which I think you may not. About quotations: The purpose of them is to refer to specific statements. That's why I make use of them.