# let $L:V \to U,$ and $M:U \to W$ be linear mappings if $M\circ L$ is one-to-one then $L$ is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

a problem asks me to prove or disprove the following statement
let $L:V \to U,$ and $M:U \to W$ be linear mappings if $M\circ L$ is one-to-one then $L$ is one-to-one

This is my attempt at proving the statement let $\vec{x} \in ker(L)$
then $M\circ L(\vec{x})=M(L(\vec{x}))=M(\vec{0})=0$ thus $\vec{x} \in ker(M\circ L)$

Comment: You are incorrect in claiming that if $\vec{x}$ is in the kernel of $M\circ L$ then it must be in the kernel of $L$. That is not true in general, but is not needed here. Your first part shows that $\vec{x}\in\mathrm{ker}(L)$ implies $\vec{x}\in\mathrm{ker}(M\circ L)$, and you are assuming that the latter is $\{\vec{0}\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so the fact that it is in ker(MoL) is enough to conlcude that $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$?

Comment: The fact that $M\circ L$ is assumed to be one-to-one tells you that $\mathrm{ker}(M\circ L) = \{\vec{0}\}$. The fact that $\vec{x}$ is in $\mathrm{ker}(M\circ L)$ then tells you that $\vec{x}$ is an element of $\{\vec{0}\}$. What are the possibilities? P.S. The composition symbol is `\circ`, not `o`. So `M\circ L` to get $M\circ L$.

Comment: well then $\vec{x}$ has to be $\vec{0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, there's a much simpler way to do this. Just take some $x, x'\in V$ that are not equal. Suppose that $L$ is not injective. Then $M \circ L(x)\neq M\circ L(x')$. Clearly, due to $M$ being well-defined, it follows that $L(x)\neq L(x' )$, and due to $M\circ L$ being injective, this holds for all pairs of points $x, x'\in V\Rightarrow L$ is injective. In fact, it's more than this and it holds for more than linear maps; you can check out [Eric Towers' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699454).

Comment: Kernels determine one-to-one-ness in linear transformations. It's good practice to use linearity when working with linear transformations.

While it is true that this particular statement holds at the level of set functions, and so linearity is not really needed, there's nothing wrong with using kernels to test linearity when dealing with linear transformations.

Comment: Of course, I agree with you completely on that. But as you pointed out, this holds for a lot more than linear maps, and I don't see how using that leads to a(n) (efficient) proof in this case.

Comment: You are lacking context; maybe this is a problem for students to get used to using or arguing about kernels? Personally I find it frustrating that when dealing with linear transformations, students will continually go to "assume $x\neq y$, we must show $L(x)\neq L(y)$", rather than think about kernels.  While there is nothing "more efficient" here, it is also not *less* efficient to use kernels if all you care about are linear transformations.

Comment: Fair enough, I see your point.

Comment: That said, it is absolutely a good point to add "By the way, this statement holds for arbitrary functions, not just linear transformations."

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I haven't really participated very actively here, so it's good to get some pointers. I'll make some changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that $\ker (M\circ L)\supseteq \ker L$, as you showed correctly. In general it is not true that $\ker (M\circ L)=\ker L$, which is a surprisingly common characteristic of sentences that are introduced by the phrase "*Similarly, I can show that...*".